# Unclear Segmentation Fault returning 139

Tags: c, c89

I try to write a sudoku solver
I always get a segmentation fault after calling getPossibleElements in solveSudoku.
If I delete this line the error doesnt appear.

My Code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define SUDOKU_X 8
#define SUDOKU_Y 8
#define MAX_FILENAME 50
#define MAX_POSSIBILITIES 8

typedef enum bool {false, true} bool;

void printPossibilities (bool numbers[], const int pos_x, const int pos_y) {
  int i = 0;

  for (i = 0; i <= MAX_POSSIBILITIES; i++) {
    if (numbers[i]) {
      printf("%d ", (i+1));
    }
  }
}

void getPossibleElements (bool numbers[],int a[][SUDOKU_Y], const int pos_x, const int pos_y) {
  int x = 0;
  int y = 0;
  int i = 0;
  int j = 0;
  int tmp = 0;

  for (x = 0; x <= MAX_POSSIBILITIES; x++) {
    numbers[x] = true;
  }

  /* row */
  for (x = 0; x <= SUDOKU_X; x++) {
    if (a[pos_y][x] > 0) {
        printf("ROW->a[%d][%d]\n",pos_y,x);
        printf("ROW->%d\n",a[pos_y][x]-1);
      numbers[a[pos_y][x]-1] = false;
    }
  }
  /* coloumn */
  for (y = 0; y <= SUDOKU_Y; y++) {
    if (a[y][pos_x] > 0) {
        printf("coloumn->a[%d][%d]\n",y,pos_x);
        printf("coloumn->%d\n",a[y][pos_x]-1);
      numbers[a[y][pos_x]-1] = false;
    }
  }
  /* field */
if (pos_x <= 2 && pos_y <= 2) {
    x = 0;
    y = 0;
  }
  else if (pos_x <= 5 && pos_y <= 2) {
    x = 3;
    y = 0;
  }
  else if (pos_x <= 8 && pos_y <= 2) {
    x = 6;
    y = 0;
  }
  else if (pos_x <= 2 && pos_y <= 5) {
    x = 0;
    y = 3;
  }
  else if (pos_x <= 5 && pos_y <= 5) {
    x = 3;
    y = 3;
  }
  else if (pos_x <= 8 && pos_y <= 5) {
    x = 6;
    y = 3;
  }
  else if (pos_x <= 2) {
    x = 0;
    y = 6;
  }
  else if (pos_x <= 5) {
    x = 3;
    y = 6;
  }
  else if (pos_x <= 8) {
    x = 6;
    y = 6;
  }

  printf("DB!!! x=%d y=%d\n", x,y);


  for (j = y; j < (y+3); j++) {
    for (i = x; i < (x+3); i++) {
      if (a[j][i] > 0) {
        printf("FIELD->a[%d][%d]\n",j,i);
        printf("FIELD->%d\n",(a[j][i])-1);
        numbers[(a[j][i])-1] = false;
      }
    }
  }
  printf("db");
}



void printSudoku (int a[][SUDOKU_Y]) {
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    printf("-------------------------------\n");
    for (j = 0; j <= SUDOKU_X; j++)
    {
      for (i = 0; i <= SUDOKU_Y; i++) {
        if (i == 0) {
          printf("|");
        }
        printf(" %d ",a[j][i]);
        if (i == 2 || i == 5 || i == 8) {
          printf("|");
        }
      }
      printf("\n");
      if (j == 2 || j == 5) {
        printf("|-----------------------------|\n");
      }
    }
    printf("-------------------------------\n");
}/* printSudoku */

bool solveSudoku (int a [][SUDOKU_Y]) {
  bool numbers[MAX_POSSIBILITIES];
  int x = 0;
  int y = 0;

  printSudoku(a);
  getPossibleElements(numbers,a,x,y);
  printPossibilities(numbers,x,y);
  return true;
}
void readFiletoArray (const char * fileName, int a[][SUDOKU_Y])
{
    FILE *fp = fopen(fileName,"r");
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int val0 = 0;
    int val1 = 0;
    int val2 = 0;

    if( fp == NULL ) {
      perror("Error while opening the file.\n");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    while(fscanf(fp, "%d %d %d", &val0, &val1, &val2) > 0) {
      a[j][i++] = val0;
      a[j][i++] = val1;
      a[j][i++] = val2;
      if (i >= 8) {
        i = 0;
        j++;
      }
    }
    fclose(fp);
} /* readFiletoArray */

int main (int argc, char * argv []) {
  int a[SUDOKU_X][SUDOKU_Y];
  char fileName[MAX_FILENAME];
  bool numbers[MAX_POSSIBILITIES];
  bool success = false;

  if(argc == 2) {
    strncpy(fileName, argv[1], MAX_FILENAME-1);
    fileName[MAX_FILENAME] = '\0';
  }
  else {
    printf("ERROR: Invalid Parameter\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  readFiletoArray(fileName, a);

  success = solveSudoku(a);

  printf("DB");
  exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
} /* Main */
```

sudoku.txt (Program Parameter)

```
0 5 9 0 4 0 2 0 0
0 1 0 0 5 0 0 0 7
4 0 0 3 2 9 0 1 5
3 2 0 1 0 0 9 0 0
0 0 7 4 0 6 5 0 0
0 0 4 0 0 5 0 7 8
6 9 0 5 0 3 0 0 4
5 0 0 0 6 0 0 3 0
0 0 8 0 1 0 6 5 0
```

Thx

Comment: You're going off the end of the array. Try `i < MAX_POSSIBILITIES;` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At a glance, this is because you are running off the end of the array in various places.

```
for (x = 0; x <= MAX_POSSIBILITIES; x++) { // 0,1,2...8
```

See that `<=` you have there? That's your problem.

`numbers` is declared as `bool numbers[MAX_POSSIBILITIES];`, and array indices in C start at `0` and go to `length - 1`. Zero through seven in this case, but you are trying to access `numbers[8]`.

You have the same issue elsewhere. `a` is declared as

```
int a[SUDOKU_X][SUDOKU_Y]; // int a[8][8];
```

and in `getPossibleElements` you are iterating from 0 to 8 inclusive, like so:

```
for (x = 0; x <= SUDOKU_X; x++) { 
...
for (y = 0; y <= SUDOKU_Y; y++) {
```

...thus running off the end of your array again.

Same deal in `printPossibilities`.

Change `MAX_POSSIBILITIES`, `SUDOKU_X` and `SUDOKU_Y` to be `9` in your `#define`s and iterate from 0 to 8 by doing

```
for (x = 0; x < SUDOKU_X; x++) { // 0,1,2...8
```

One more thing. You should fix your `fileName` stuff too. Same deal. The last index in an array is `length - 1`, not `length`. If you had warnings cranked up when you compiled, it probably would have mentioned this one.

```
if (argc == 2) {
    strncpy(fileName, argv[1], MAX_FILENAME - 2); // was MAX_FILENAME - 1
    fileName[MAX_FILENAME - 1] = '\0'; // was [MAX_FILENAME]
}
```

Comment: @user547995 See my most recent edit for another issue.